# C comparing binary numbers with xor

Tags: c

this is part of the code. Here, I want to compare digits by xor.
So it suppose to give "0111" but it gives "111" as result.
How can I fix it?
So it suppose to give "0111" but it gives "111" as result.
How can I fix it?

```
1 and 1 = 0
1 and 0 = 1
0 and 1 = 1
0 and 0 = 0



#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()

{   
    int BinaryRepForDisk1=1101, BinaryRepForDisk2=1010, Disk3=0, xor1, xor2, power=0;

    while(BinaryRepForDisk1!=0)
    {
        xor1=BinaryRepForDisk1%2;
        xor2=BinaryRepForDisk2%2;

        if(xor1==xor2)
        {
            Disk3=Disk3+pow(10,power)*0;
            power++;
        }

        else
        {
            Disk3=Disk3+pow(10,power)*1;
            power++;        
        }   

        BinaryRepForDisk1=BinaryRepForDisk1/10;
        BinaryRepForDisk2=BinaryRepForDisk2/10;
    }   
    printf("%d",Disk3);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *`int BinaryRepForDisk1=1101`* -- this is not a number represented in binary. It is one thousand one hundred and one.

Comment: `111` and `0111` are equal.

Comment: @jadhachem: Ehm... no!

Comment: yes but think as if it is binary

Comment: Please read [ask]. _How can I fix it_ says absoluely nothing about the problem you're having. Your question itself is basically a debugging request with very little information, which makes it off-topic here.

Comment: why it should give `0111`?

Comment: @Olaf yes, seeing as the result `Disk3` is being printed as `printf("%d")`

Comment: @jadhachem: Ok, as an output it is. Sorry, the question is a bit confusing.

Comment: @olaf If it's confusing, don't answer it. We have close reasons for confusing questions.

Comment: sorry i m new here

Comment: Note that `int %2` will result in `0,1,-1`.  Recommend using `unsigned` types or `&1` to get only 2 different results `0,1`.

Comment: @dandan78: Thanks for the info. I really was not aware. Oh, and comments are not to be used for answers. Sorry, if that looked like an answer to you.

Answer (score 0):

It is the same number, because you're working with decimals. The only thing is that, if you want the print result to be enforced to be 4 digits and padded with zeroes, use a different print formatter instead:

```
printf("%04d",Disk3);
```

Comment: But I recommend using real binary representations and xor operation, unless you're doing this for some other purpose.

Comment: but value of BinaryRepForDisk1 and BinaryRepForDisk2 is changeable. I wrote these values as an example

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with binary numbers, you need to use **0b** before the number:

```
int BinaryDisk1 = 0b1101, BinaryDisk2 = 0b1010;
```

C also have a xor bit a bit:

```
int result = BinaryDisk1 ^ BinaryDisk2;
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
int BinaryRepForDisk1=1101, BinaryRepForDisk2=1010;
```

You are initializing `BinaryRepForDisk1` to the decimal number `1101`, not the binary number `1101`. To get the decimal equivalent of the binary `1101`, you can use:

```
int BinaryRepForDisk1= ( (1 << 3) + (1 << 2) + 0 + 1);
// You can use (0 << 1) to keep the familiar structure but its not needed.
```

If your compiler supports binary literals, you can use:

```
int BinaryRepForDisk1= 0b1101;
```

You can make similar adjustments to the value of `BinaryRepForDisk2`.